# JPA, updating all values by percent

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I would like to update all prices in my Entity by given percent. My code:

```
@Override
public List<ProductDTO> updatePriceByPercent(double percent) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<ProductDTO> q = em.createNamedQuery("ProductDTO.updatePriceByProcent", ProductDTO.class);
    q.setParameter("percent", percent);
    q.executeUpdate();
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

And my query looks like:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "ProductDTO.updatePriceByPercent", query="update ProductDTO set price += price * :percent")
```

and that's giving me following error:

> [29, 30] The UPDATE clause has 'price  +' and '= price * :percent' that are not separated by a comma.
>
> [28, 28] The equal sign must be specified.
>
> [30, 30] An arithmetic factor must be followed by an expression.
>
> [30, 30] The state field path expression is missing.
>
> [32, 37] The left expression is not an arithmetic expression.

Comment: have you tried `set price = price + price * :percent`? I'm not sure `+=` is part of the sql standard

Comment: Yes, I tried it, it's still giving me:
> [38, 43] The left expression is not an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
 price = price * (1 + :percent)
```

I don't think `+=` is supported. [Reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL)

Comment: This solution is also giving me: [30, 35] The left expression is not an arithmetic expression.

Comment: Also check the ref link. You have some error in the query.